# How to query exactly selected items in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

According to my understanding, `project.getItems({selected: true})` returns wrong results: I'm selecting a curve, it returns the parent Path: [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/nVVNb9swDP0rhBE0Npq6afYFxCt26HbYYcOADtih6UGxmViNIgWSXDco8t9HybLjtE1XLIBtSXyPfKJI5TGSbI3RNLpeoc3LaBTlqnDze6ahVnrFtKpkAZewYMLgTM+ke5x1vRVcIlkk1vCL2TL2A8WljS/G4xHQK0kyB2+gqbFarfBKCaWJNtRYDJ9Z//DClmS9GLexgpkVRS/ApAtwHPLRQT4FyPk5GBSYW1BSbMGW3EBe6XuEOdoaUQKbK5ox2uwchaoJvlyjtOZogHddADiKeT8hzORDEOEeU/KFbbMWkuW2kgBJtKpmujAwV9aq9Znmy9L2c+7J3y2us86Vm7njqWRuuZIxp/kIChSWJY8OBeCYfDCCB3o0LugtUNJ7O8gagKk5HT54brpEeyWYMT+pMGLaW3CSM4MwvHIpG06bJYAFnWTMBxR/3DilUexC0PfGewtZvBhBfzq5TVKCL22ZkTL47LkZnJ7yQRfQ/R6cI+fvhg9us/56unG5g9PLZqudbdcO5hrZKutrdzX6NultHq5DCVAa3iR3e0Tu9qncN6gNsfeCvaiX3bywV4c75L7KKnDBKmGfBjPc1dQTphe9y9q6bCuPGuuHqgx+VbWM8Z60J11q2hb3HYgH14kzl9x1xIZtUKcbre4IlNLabzS28dTsO+nULWJHOTlxzFSonDkBSe8kIDT35QEi9YvPUH1dVlcHgN4d+GXffrHnjZqFBKYgKyGeHSrSFkkr9MWGBjgoG2jvmiA3zF4A/IfSwPyX1vbbpp+q39FN/NiGnPqIuySlzvnG8jLurhw1v+vnPlfSKIGU9aU37S0HEp0MUrNXSthWZSevG/WdzqKzV3+zyNN29G/ma9wXj4mmN7e7vw==)

Try clicking on a curve or a segment. Whole path will be moved. Then try changing the behavior by setting `var workaround = false` to `var workaround = true` to observe desired behavior.

How can I get exactly what is really selected?

### Current workaround

I'm currently adding those objects into an array on selection and use those items instead of `project.getItems({selected: true})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that in `Paper.js` architecture, [curves](http://paperjs.org/reference/curve/) and [segments](http://paperjs.org/reference/segment/) are not [items](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/) (they are part of a specific `item` which is the `path`). So you shouldn't expect [project.getItems()](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#getitems-options) to return anything else than `items`.

Another thing you have to know is that a path is assumed selected if any of its part is selected (`curves`, `segments`, `points`, `handles`, `position`, `bounds`, ...). And a curve is assumed selected if all of its parts are selected (`points` and `handles`).

With that in mind, you can create an algorithm to retrieve "what is really selected" based on `project.getItems({selected: true})` as its first part. Then, you need to loop through `curves` and `segments` to check if they are selected.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/lVbbThsxEP2VUR7KRkTbQG9SaJ5oq1ZqS1WQeAAezO4k68ZrR7aTCKH8e2e8N29IaFmJZDNz5nju5nGgRYmDyeBygT4rBqNBZnL+vRYW1ph5Y2EKGjfwy0jtk5PxCE7Gw7Nbe6v57/VrOLcoPMJS+CJlEVvyj8aOXpNHVgA9Duclau8mcNOI+Lk5GQfi8d2oJz49IH7P4g+74jf7xW9PSXz6bnzXSDu989Ys8NwoYydwZDE/2lFdy9wXE3KBxdte3FdWaKc49LlcowZfSD0HoQx9zpW5F6pOYMjKbKUzLw3BGrMrxifBaghdgjaS6gCVPJ2jP1fCuZ9UpGQYwfjJhEM44vweTWI5P5X50jgZDj2e1r6c7QLvqXqLs6e05yu7xkO8dRVP6ABqimfYe/DTf8IPOXNZERwO8yW021DKqJAXGkqzonNys9Fp2i+X0T9Y94lUCVKZfVQEsiW40eqB+lrR2bApBH0IB5mS2QLztIGG6ahAmNNkzIRy2LpUSE+ypViiTZfW/CFUSrIrdL46tApx2BrIGSRs9OoV26bKZIK93WmQWJVmXNDYBW9X2E8KvyD5tUtf128Pe615njZK1zVCVmC2oDFRID2WDma0YXIsDSxXlvoV0wj+w6wxQFv+UHAXY75I6zzQoHSgilhqEFRDYlDigRKbdsWoU1ypvwctEXxjs+Sx5ZmEWGA77NfbFzTspViSL1iCN1XRpQPqMtW2AtW+OzAleEInXNaqMPr7aNvlEMg7e0rSZ5EVSX95VP0QtzKJHZToC5OTO35ltTvkXshPvbo4YWlN8RUtwobS7tyqZD/IOrS40VjvuExouMeOiRDkLjjBeFliQ/U7eNBUrTFDSWBLZ4cVM6KXeryBOoEg3xpn2hnczVzC/vbn8II9rForNLojpry9bbih2YbTILqbqpmkEH5/1cJ0Oq13607b840XnZPGOu7lhO8/SYNAl46ir0BeYxXquS/OSP0RFH0dH++Q9zyqjG7kXTtee9D8VJWGvtGTLbiNBdu9ITX5+r+gWvTLwmrMXhhYZPafoW2j/oiY4P6BFs5MrJRv44zU3UzRP0Ph5gi71w0mN3fbvw==) demonstrating a possible solution.

```
var vector = new Point(10, 10);

// Create path.
var path = new Path({
    segments: [
        [100, 100],
        [200, 100],
        [260, 170],
        [360, 170],
        [420, 250]
    ],
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 10
});

// Translate given thing along global vector.
function translateThing(thing) {
    switch (thing.getClassName()) {
        case 'Path':
            thing.position += vector;
            break;
        case 'Curve':
            thing.segment1.point += vector;
            thing.segment2.point += vector;
            break;
        case 'Segment':
            thing.point += vector;
            break;
    }
}

// On mouse down...
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // ...only select what was clicked.
    path.selected = false;
    hit = paper.project.hitTest(event.point);
    if (hit && hit.location) {
        hit.location.curve.selected = true;
    }
    else if (hit && hit.segment) {
        hit.segment.selected = true;
    }

    // We check all items for demo purpose.
    // Move all selected things.
    // First get selected items in active layer...
    project.activeLayer.getItems({ selected: true })
    // ...then map them to what is really selected...
    .map(getSelectedThing)
    // ...then translate them.
    .forEach(translateThing);
}

// This method returns what is really selected in a given item.
// Here we assume that only one thing can be selected at the same time.
// Returned thing can be either a Curve, a Segment or an Item.
function getSelectedThing(item) {
    // Only check curves and segments if item is a path.
    if (item.getClassName() === 'Path') {
        // Check curves.
        for (var i = 0, l = item.curves.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (item.curves[i].selected) {
                return item.curves[i];
            }
        }
        // Check segments.
        for (var i = 0, l = item.segments.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (item.segments[i].selected) {
                return item.segments[i];
            }
        }
    }
    // return item by default.
    return item;
}
```

That said, depending on your real use case, your current workaround could be more appropriate than this approach.

Comment: Interpreting this answer as "This behavior is expected and there is no straight approach for original question"